# How to convert an ObservableCollection to XML file from C#?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

How can we, convert an `ObserableCollection<collectionName>` to  XML file from C# & WPF?

Comment: editing the question only happening , there is no answers coming up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy using this code i easily convert the collection to xml file.

```
 static private DataTable ResultsData = new DataTable();
 ResultsData = obserableCollectionName().ToDataTable();

 System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 ResultsData.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, false);
 string result = writer.ToString();
```

Comment: What does obserableCollectionName() mean? I'm not following

Comment: @Richard, it is the name given for the  function which having the data