# Can we convert, DataTable to XML in C# Directly?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Any body say how can we convert a data-table to XML format.
I tried the below one but is is not saving or exporting the data

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail>));
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("customers.xml"))
{
    xs.Serialize(wr, DetailReportFCBuySell1);
}
```

Comment: thnaks i got an answer from this [From This Link Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345073/how-to-convert-an-observablecollection-to-xml-file-from-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DataTable dtSample = new DataTable();
dtSample.WriteXml(fileName); //Pass the path of the XML file.
```